# Перебор ip адресов в диапазоне

Tags: python, ip, ip-address, перебор

Есть диапазон ip адресов задаваемый в виде `192.168.0.1-192.168.0.3`, и надо его пропинговать. У меня есть идея в таком виде: начиная с крайнего правого октета начинать перебор и отсылать запросы. Я реализую это так:

```
def ping(ip_p_1,ip_p_2):
if (int(ip_p_1[3]) < int(ip_p_2[3])):
    for i in range(int(ip_p_1[3]),int(ip_p_2[3])+1):
        ip_p_1[3] = str(i)
        request(ip_p_1)
```

Но это будет работать в том случае, если последний октет конечного ip больше начального, а если диапазон задан в виде `192.168.0.3-192.168.0.1`?
И еще одна проблема, как в таком случае реализовать перебор, если, например, второй октет с конца конечного адреса больше,например : `192.168.0.1-192.168.3.1`? Подскажите направление в реализации данного алгоритма или, если есть подобные решения, ссылки на них.

Comment: Преобразуешь оба адреса в число. Вот тебе границы цикла. Внутри - делаешь обратное преобразование и пингуешь.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Благодарю!

Comment: @Akina, а обратное преобразование вообще нужно? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX0SD.png

Comment: @Qwertiy Добрый сетевой реквестор к адресу запросто может присовокупить домен... насколько я понимаю, товарищ не внешней утилитой пингать будет.

Comment: @Akina, не знаю, чем, но я просто предположил, что это что-то может и само число сожрать.

Comment: Можно не изобретать  все заново - https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html